# When someone is ordered by court to publish a statement saying that their earlier allegation is wrong (in slander cases), what do you call that?

Tags: word-request

Does the person refute his earlier claim? Disown? Disclaim? Retract? What verbs could be used in that case? If I just look at the definitions, they all fit, but I doubt that I can use all or, maybe, even any of them in my circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Refute" is provide evidence to prove the claim wrong.

"Disown" is to deny that something is connected to you (for example if you say that you never believed what you said).

"Disclaim" is when you deny responsibility for something.

The only word that means "publish a statement saying their earlier allegation was wrong" is "retract".

Comment: "Deny or contradict" — fits, "refuse to maintain any connection with" — fits, "refuse to acknowledge" — fits. That what I meant. The definitions taken alone may be misleading. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Statements or allegations are retracted in legal English.